# How to remove public directory from url in codeigniter version 4.4.3

Tags: codeigniter

Please any one solve my problem

While I am using the codeigniter version 4.4.3 it's show a public directory, I want remove public directory from my url. I tried to many types include when asking chatgpt it's not working.